# PouchDb Large Attachments on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic2, attachment, pouchdb

I've got a hybrid app (Ionic 2) that stores files as attachments in PouchDb.  I'm running into a problem on iOS where attachments (blob format) greater than ~50mb cause a crash when calling putAttachment.  I've read a lot of stuff about quotas etc.  As a result I'm using the cordova-sqlite adapter I've tried both Cordova-sqlite-storage and cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 plugins) for iOS.  I thought this should get around any quota issues. Or does this not apply to attachments?  Unfortunately I do not get back any error / exception messages to help with further debugging.  Any pointers appreciated.

```
    self.db.post(navItemFile).then(function (response) {
        let newDocId = response.id;
        self.db.putAttachment(newDocId, fileName, response.rev, blob,   contentType).then(function () {
            resolve(newDocId);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            Raven.captureException(err);
            resolve(newDocId);
        });
    });
```

Comment: In some cases, I personally prefer to upload large attachments somewhere on the cloud and then just keep the link inside the CouchDB/PouchDB doc. I'm not sure if it suits your case.

Comment: @user4838962 - in my case I want to give offline access to these files.

Comment: why you cant use `base64` type to store that attachement. Did you tried that?

Comment: @DilankaRathnayake - thanks for the suggestion.  Did not help in my situation.  I think that I am going to resort to storing files natively on iOS.  I cannot find any other solution - despite trying multiple other options, including the FruitDown adapter.